# I'm asking only because or i'm only asking because- what would be the proper or better sounding version

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-starts

I seem to be excessively over analyzing the superior manner in which the sentence ought to begin. The proceeding phrases are what I need advice with, so as to decide the proper wording, to initiate the sentence opening. I'm simply asking what would be most applicable or appropriate sounding version of the two...

Answer (score 2):

"I'm only asking..."  is an *apology* for daring to ask.

Example

> "What's that you are holding?"
>
> "None of your business."
>
> "Oh, sorry, I was only asking."  *(This means "I was merely asking")*

---

"I'm asking only because ..." is an *explanation* for asking.

> "What's that you are holding?"
>
> "Why?"
>
> "I'm asking only because it's leaked on the carpet. I'm hoping it won't leave a stain."  *(This means "I was asking for the sole reason that ...")*